# Error on Programmatically changing the SelectManyCheckbox List in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a SelectManyChecbox on my jsff which is bound to a list in the managed bean.

Now my issues is that when i click on certain radio button, some of the check boxes should get removed, ie the list should be updated to have lesser number of check boxes.

Now when i have selected lets say 5 out of the 10 check boxes, and now when i update the list, it leaves me with only 2 options in the check boxes...and at this point ADF faces raise an issue that the selection should be limited and all.

please tell me how to reset the checkboxes to default/unselected state before updating the list.

or is there any other way to get rid of this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my example, and it works:

```
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
<af:document title="main.jsf" id="d1">
    <af:form id="f1">
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1">
            <af:selectOneRadio label="setValues" id="sor1" autoSubmit="true"
                               valueChangeListener="#{viewScope.test.onSetValues}" value="#{viewScope.test.values}">
                <af:selectItem label="5 values" value="0" id="si2"/>
                <af:selectItem label="3 values" value="1" id="si3"/>
            </af:selectOneRadio>
            <af:selectManyChoice label="selectManyCheckBox" id="smc1" binding="#{viewScope.test.comp}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{viewScope.test.list}" id="si1"/>
            </af:selectManyChoice>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </af:form>
</af:document>
```

```
public class TestBean {

private ArrayList<SelectItem> list;
private long values;
private RichSelectManyChoice comp;

public TestBean() {
    super();
    list = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    restoreList();
}

private void restoreList() {
    list.clear();
    list.add(new SelectItem(false, "value 1"));
    list.add(new SelectItem(false, "value 2"));
    list.add(new SelectItem(false, "value 3"));
    list.add(new SelectItem(false, "value 4"));
    list.add(new SelectItem(false, "value 5"));
}

private void cutList() {
    list.clear();
    list.add(new SelectItem(false, "value 1"));
    list.add(new SelectItem(false, "value 2"));
    list.add(new SelectItem(false, "value 3"));
}

public void setList(ArrayList<SelectItem> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public ArrayList<SelectItem> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void onSetValues(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    if ((Long)valueChangeEvent.getNewValue() == 0) 
        restoreList();
    else {            
        cutList();
    }
    comp.setValue(null);
    comp.processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(comp);        
}

public void setValues(long values) {
    this.values = values;
}

public long getValues() {
    return values;
}

public void setComp(RichSelectManyChoice comp) {
    this.comp = comp;
}

public RichSelectManyChoice getComp() {
    return comp;
}
```